# Is it possible to control the installation of a common profile in the MDM profile?

Tags: mdm

I am looking at MDM work.

I think the MDM profile created using SCEP on the server cannot prevent deletion.

So I want to install and manage a controlable MDM profile and a generic profile at the same time.

How can I use the screen-capture prevention feature to create a generic profile and then manage the generic profile with the MDM profile?

However, it is cumbersome to install the profile twice.

I thought that after installing the MDM profile, it will automatically install the general profile or move it to the installable screen.

I am curious about the above contents and possible solutions.